# Swagger to HTML converter with results like Strava or Paypal

Tags: html, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I've been search for a couple of months now for nice swagger to HTML converter and I can't seem to find anything that will generate something that looks like the Strava API reference (https://strava.github.io/api/v3/routes/#list) or the Paypal API reference (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_create).

They are not the only one with this template so I'm guessing it's an HTML generator that I just couldn't find with my google search skills. Anybody knows how to generate doc looking like this without coding it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have the Swagger/OpenAPI spec, you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate documentation.

1. Go to https://editor.swagger.io
2. Import your Swagger spec under "File" in the top menu
3. Under "Generate Client" in the top menu, select Html2 (preferred), HTML or dynamic HTML.

(https://editor.swagger.io leverages https://generator.swagger.io to generate code and https://generater.swagger.io is powered by swagger-codegen)